# Return records from azure search that match the exact search term only

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

So I'm new to Azure search and I'm only starting to figure it out. I have a search index that queries a pretty simple sql view for matching records. I'm having major trouble getting an exact match for the word I search for.

Whenever I search I get records with the exact word only.. however I also get records that contain the searched for word  e.g I search for "Type" and I get "New Type" and "My Type". I'm enclosing "Type" in double quotes when I search.

I'm using the C# SDK, and it also happens when I execute a search via Postman:

`https://myapp.search.windows.net/indexes/myindex/docs?$select=AlertDate,DocumentName,City,DocumentType&search=(DocumentType:"Type")&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&api-version=2016-09-01`

Any idea what might cause this and how I can get exact matches only? I've read a fair bit on it and several posts and web pages say that wrapping the search term in double quotes will get the exact term only, but this doesn't seem to be correct at least not for me.

Edit:

For completeness I should add the call that I'm using in C# to retrieve the results:

```
var result = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync(query, new SearchParameters()   
{ Facets = parameters.Facets, QueryType = QueryType.Full, SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,   
Top = request.Top, Skip = request.Skip, IncludeTotalResultCount = true });
```

Sometimes the search would be just a single word or multiple words, other times it could be filters that a user would select from drop downs such as Country and City, or a combination of both. I then form the query string like this:

`(Country:"France" OR "Germany") AND (City:"Paris")`

If it also includes a search term the query would look like this:

`"Type" AND (Country:"Italy" OR "France") AND (City:"Paris" OR "Rome")`

Answer (score 3):

Enclosing a query in double quotes turns it into a phrase query. This is only meaningful if there is more than one term between the quotes, separated by whitespace, punctuation etc. For example, if your search string is `Hello world`, it will match documents that contain "hello" or "world" (if you're using the default `searchMode` of `any` and assuming you don't use any other operators explicitly), but if your search string is `"Hello world"`, then documents only match if the two terms are adjacent to each other.

Looking at your query, I'm guessing you want to filter by categorical data. If you truly want an exact match (case-sensitive), then you should use $filter instead of search:

`https://myapp.search.windows.net/indexes/myindex/docs?$select=AlertDate,DocumentName,City,DocumentType&$filter=DocumentType eq 'Type'&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&api-version=2016-09-01`

Here are a few useful links for constructing filter and search queries in Azure Search:

https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search
https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search

Comment: Hi @Bruce thanks for the answer. It's taking me a while to figure out all the options, paramaters, settings etc... there's a lot of combinations :) It's also hard to differentiate between the C# and rest api search methods and the options used for each. I tried using filters originally but kept getting syntax errors, so in the end I munged the term and filters into the search query as I added above. I'll try the filters again to see if I can get them to work.

Comment: Hi again @Bruce, one problem I just realised with using filters is that for the search term I don't want to narrow it down to a specific field - I want to search for the term across all fields. When a user enters the search term I have no way of knowing what field it applies to. With the drop down I can specify the particular field and then use filters but not with the search term.

Comment: You can use filter and search together in the same request. They are effectively ANDed together. Use search for the terms entered by the user, and use filter for things like fixed categories or other fields for which the user specifies precise criteria.

Comment: @some_randomer If you found this answer useful, please consider marking it as Accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Brue thanks for the update. You say "Use search for the terms entered by the user" but this still leaves me with the original problem - searching for "Type" will also return "New Type" and "My Type".

Comment: What is Type in this example? If it's one of a small number of fixed options, why not model it as a drop-down list or something similar in your UI? It would help if you explain in a bit more detail what your UX is like and what your users are searching for.

Comment: There are about 15 different text fields in the azure search index.. we want to be able to search all of these with a free text field, and match exact words only. We also have drop downs containing filter values relating to each field

Comment: What is it about your domain that makes exact matching desirable? Doesn't this eliminate much of the benefit of full-text search? For example, if a user types "mice", would they not expect (or at least appreciate) to also get a hit on "mouse"?

Comment: Well so far this is the use case I have to implement. If it's not possible to do an exact match then I can explain this and see if the po will accept that it works this way. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try the OData filter if you want to perform exact match? In this case your query will become $filter=DocumentType eq 'Type'

Note that if you you the preview version of azure search, api-version=2015-02-28-Preview, they have added new filters for partial matching.

search.ismatch("filedvalue", "fieddname") and saerch.ismatchscoring()

Also, did you checked the Custom Analyzer? If you know that you will be always performing exact match on few fields then use "keyword" analyzer  with lowercase tokeniser

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search