# Azure Search Index - Keyword Analyzer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have a C# application that make use of the azure search index. We have an attribute in the index (say Name). This field is created with Keyword Analyzer. The requirement for me is if i search for **George Joseph** i should get only the records which have name **George Joseph** and it should not return names - **George** OR **Joseph** OR **George Joseph Sr**

If i write the search query as `Name:("George Joseph")` , will the index return the results correctly?

Regards,

John

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can also use [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search) for exact matching `$filter=Name eq 'George Joseph'`. Your question is similar to: [Return records from azure search that match the exact serch term only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332467/return-records-from-azure-search-that-match-the-exact-serch-term-only). To learn more about customizing the process query and document processing for search, please see: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture).

Comment: Actually i do not want to use the filter. I want to accomplish this using the search text. Will this work - Name:("George Joseph")?

Comment: Yes. I tried it and worked. But could not find any documentation for that in msdn. Just wanted to see if I am going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. Take a look at the article I'm linking to in my answer. It explains it.